# ASP. NET caching equivalent in PHP with Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, data-structures

I'm looking for a ASP .NET Caching equivalent for a PHP website app using Zend Framework. I want to be able to store a data structure (Queue) that can be shared between users, preserving consistency, without using a database. I don't want the cache to expire as I want the Queue to be always available when a user arrives on the website. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out PHP's [Memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php), which is a method for interfacing with memcached.